# Sharing app from PlayStore on facebook shows thai language characters in thumbnail?

Tags: android, facebook, mobile, google-play-services, share

When I share app from android playstore on facebook, it shows some Thai language characters in thumbnail. 
How did those characters come and how can i get rid of them.

Here is the app home page and sharing page on facebook.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think its your app desc from playstore

Comment: the app desc is in English language, why it is showing some other language?

Comment: share your app link.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.goplus.in.myapplication&hl=en

Comment: yumis and shuttl? what is the relation?

Comment: You sure you are sharing the correct link?

Comment: sorry, I edited the link

Comment: have u checked your phone lang or facebook lang.?

Comment: i use only english language in both mobile and facebook, some app sharing does not show this language(Thai), they are working fine.

Comment: Are you sure that's the full link? There's no locale specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding "&hl=en" at the end of sharing link solved the problem.